# Need help trying to make BLE device be discovered

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

I am trying to create a custom device to connect to an app via BLE. The device can be discovered using nRF connect and other BLE scanners, but not with the app i'm trying to use. Any idea what the issue is? Could it be something with the UUID?

Comment: Hi. Maybe you could post your code? And on which platform are you making your app?

Comment: Platform (OS)? Application?

Comment: I cant post the code for reasons, but i'm using an esp32 module. Could it be that i'm advertising the wrong services?